# Network address and Host address?

Tags: networking

What is the net id,host id and subnet address of the ip 176.184.238.73/16
Mask of 255.255.240.0

I got these answers but I'm not sure:

NetID:176.184.224
HostID:14.73
Subnet Address:176.184.224.0/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your message there are two subnet masks:

- /16 (CIDR notation) - 255.255.0.0
- /20 (CIDR notation) - 255.255.240.0

If your IP is 176.184.238.73 and subnet is **/16**:

- subnet: 172.184.0.0/16
- network address: 172.184.0.0
- broadcast address: 172.184.255.255
- networkID: 172.184
- hostID: 238.73

If your IP is 176.184.238.73 and subnet is **/20**:

- subnet: 172.184.224.0/20
- network address: 172.184.224.0
- broadcast address: 172.184.239.255
- networkID: 172.184.224
- hostID: 14.73